# AFNetworking upload a file to s3 equivalent to ASIHTTPRequest setData

Tags: objective-c, amazon-s3, asihttprequest, afnetworking

I am using s3 [Signing and Authentication](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/RESTAuthentication.html#RESTAuthenticationQueryStringAuth) to generate a singature to work with mobile client.

My original class is using ASIHTTPRequest but I want to transform it to AFNetworking.

By uploading a file to s3 with ASIHTTPRequest, it is simple to set some header specific for s3 and include the image as request

```
 [request setData:data withFileName:filename andContentType:"image/jpeg" forKey:key];
```

As from others suggestion, I use following code to send the image with request

```
 NSURLRequest *request = [httpClient multipartFormRequestWithMethod:@"PUT" path:@"/johnsmith/photos/puppy.jpg" parameters:nil constructingBodyWithBlock: ^(id <AFMultipartFormData> formData) {
        [formData appendPartWithFileData:imageData name:@"file" fileName:@"puppy.jpg" mimeType:@"image/jpeg"];
    }];
```

But this request replace a "Content-Type:image/jpeg" as

> Content-Type:multipart/form-data; boundary=Boundary+0xAbCdEfGbOuNdArY

It doesn't match the signed message so it is invalid to upload a file.

After further googling, I found a inputstream method

```
NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(uploadImage, 0.5f);
NSInputStream *stream = [[NSInputStream alloc]initWithData:imageData];
operation.inputStream = stream;
```

At this time, AFNetworking generate a

```
Transfer-Encoding:Chunked
```

and s3 respond an error say "A header you provided implies functionality that is not implemented"

**UPDATE** : For a workaround, I just comment the line which replace my original Content-header.

Comment: Have you taken a look at AFAmazonS3Client yet? It is based on AFNetworking's AFHTTPClient class and might be just what you are looking for. You can find it at https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFAmazonS3Client.

Comment: I have taken a look of AFAmazonS3Client. It is not mature as ASIHTTPRequest counterpart. In addition, I need a server side signing. So I need to implement my own. Anyway, thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: It makes sense to modify the source code to fit my requirement. I just want to ensure if there are simple and lazy way and what I am doing is not reinventing  wheel